# Firefox and IE not rendering ul li navigation properly - works in Chrome though

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html-lists, rendering

All my ul li lists aren't rendering properly in Firefox or IE. They are working absolutely perfectly in Chrome & Safari.

Does anyone know of any common reasons as to why this happens? Or would it be best to copy the code in here? Please help, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: please add a code extract here or on jsfiddle so we can check.

Comment: screenshot of your inconsistencies would be nice and the code also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G3ZhU/

Comment: ever find the answer? i'm having the same exact issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css normalizer to blur the initial differences across browsers - https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css